# Query to delete all duplicate rows but one where no columns is/are unique

Tags: sql, oracle

My Table Structure is like

---

```
RID int,
ColA int,
ColB varchar(1) not null,
ColC DATE not null
```

What I need to do now is delete duplicate rows but one where none of the columns are unique.

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  If the rows are duplicated, then the columns are not unique -- so the question doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using Oracle, you can use the `rowid` pseudocolumn:

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns008.htm

A query like this should work:

```
DELETE FROM the_table
WHERE rowid not in
(SELECT MIN(rowid)
  FROM the_table
  GROUP BY RID, ColA, ColB, ColC);
```

Comment: Thank you Eugen! It proved to be a great help

Comment: [Note : Usually, a rowid value uniquely identifies a row in the database. However, rows in different tables that are stored together in the same cluster can have the same rowid](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns008.htm)